# HAProxy HTTP binding stops working

Tags: haproxy

I have HAProxy 1.4.15 on CentOS 5.2 with the following configuration:

```
backend http_out
    mode        http
    option      forceclose
    option      httpclose
    option      forwardfor
    option      httpchk
    balance     roundrobin
    cookie      BACKEND insert indirect nocache maxidle 30m maxlife 8h
    server      server0 x.x.x.x:80 cookie A check inter 3s fall 3 weight 10

listen http_in
    bind        y.y.y.y:80
    default_backend http_out
```

Connectivity is good between x.x.x.x and y.y.y.y but redirection stops working after just a few minutes and always times out. If I restart the service it will work again but only for 2 more minutes. I have already tried all permutations of the options, disabling cookies, adding more servers, no checks.. always the same thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities :
  - you have nf_conntrack loaded (with default settings) and the table gets full, so you have to wait for entries to time out.
  - for an unknown reason, your clients never close their connection and you reach a point where all connections are used so
    you can't establish new ones. Check if you have set your timeouts, and if timeouts fix the issue then definitely there is
    a problem with the way connections are released.